# Centering a gnuplot figure properly

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, gnuplot

I use gnuplot and its `epslatex` terminal. When I include a gnuplot-generated figure in my document and center it as usual, it often appears shifted right — because the labels on the left contribute to the LaTeX-calculated figure width:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
  \caption{I am visually shifted right!}
  \centering
  \input{myplot}

  % Plot source:
  % 
  % set terminal epslatex color
  % set output 'myplot.tex'
  % set format '$%g$'
  % set ylabel 'A label'
  % plot 100000 * sin(x) title '$100000 \sin x$'
  % 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: Result]

The question is: how does one *properly* align such a plot, so that the center of the plot matches the center of the page horizontally? (Inserting a matching negative horizontal space manually doesn't count. `(-:`)

Comment: You can set the label with a package. For example: overpic, pstool.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this question ! I was going to ask exactly the same :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the margins of the plot in gnuplot using `lmargin at screen 0` and `rmargin at screen 1.0`, so that the plot takes up the entire canvas. The labels will still be placed correctly:

[image: epslatex gnuplot properly centred]

Comment: This is excellent!